# Python: iterating and modifying nested lists

Tags: python, list

I apologize if this question has been asked before, as it seems to be very basic. Unfortunately, when I searched for my question, I could only find other questions asking *how* to iterate over a list of lists, and none of these questions touched on the specific behavior I am asking about.

I am aware that in python, when you equate two lists, you are not actually copying that list in memory, just creating a new alais *pointing* to that list in memory. so something like

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = listA
listB[0] = 5
print(listA) #prints [5,2,3]
```

makes perfect sense to me.

I also know that you can modify mutable types (like lists) in a for loop, while for other types (like integers), you cannot, and must modify the original list. for example

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [4,5,6]
for Int in listA:
    Int +=1
print(listA) #doesn't work, prints [1,2,3]

for List in [listA,listB]:
    List[2] = 100
print(listA) #works, prints [1,2,100]
```

my problem appeared when I tried to combine these two principles. Here is an example of what I tried to do:

```
x = [1.2345,0.543895,0.0]
y = [2,3,4]
z = [65.34,3.248578493,1.11111]
for coord in [x,y,z]:
    rounded_coord = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
    coord = rounded_coord
print(x,y,z) #prints unmodified numbers
```

In this example, 'coord' is a list, and therefore I should be able to modify it, just like listA in my previous examples, but I can't. I have to use enumerate:

```
x = [1.2345,0.543895,0.0]
y = [2,3,4]
z = [65.34,3.248578493,1.11111]
coordlist = [x,y,z]
for idx,coord in enumerate(coordlist):
    coordlist[idx] = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
print(coordlist)
```

Why doesn't my original attempt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *'coord' is a list, and therefore I should be able to modify it...*

Almost, but not quite. `coord` is a variable that stores a reference to the each of the original lists in turn per iteration.

`rounded_coord` is also a variable that stores a reference to a new list.

Now, doing `coord = rounded_coord` will make the variable `coord` point to the same reference as `rounded_coord`. Meaning, the original contents of `coords` will remain unchanged while the reference that `coord` points to changes.

Example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for l in [x]:
...    print(id(l))
...    new_l = [1]
...    l = new_l
...    print(id(l))
...    
4309421160
4309421592
```

By the way, `id` prints a 10 digit number representing the reference a variable points to. You can see that at the start vs at the end, the reference stored in `l` changes.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you! I'm glad you mentioned id(), it will be extremely helpful preventing stupid mistakes like this in the future.

Comment: @C.Brooks Yup, don't worry, we've all been there.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
x = [1.2345,0.543895,0.0]
y = [2,3,4]
z = [65.34,3.248578493,1.11111]
for coord in [x,y,z]:
    rounded_coord = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
    coord = rounded_coord
print(x,y,z) #prints unmodified numbers
```

`coord` is not a list - it's a pointer to a list in your ad-hoc created `[x, y, z]` list. Since this is a relatively simple example, here is how this unpacks without a loop:

```
coord = x
rounded_coord = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
coord = rounded_coord

coord = y
rounded_coord = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
coord = rounded_coord

coord = z
rounded_coord = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
coord = rounded_coord
```

See a problem with it?

If you really wanted to change the element itself, you'd either have to reference it by index in its container list on replacement (as you've noticed that it works with `enumerate`) or to replace the value in place:

```
for coord in [x,y,z]:
    coord[:] = [round(item,3) for item in coord]  # assuming not overriden __setslice__()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use a loop of the form:

```
for item in list:
    #do something
```

The item becomes a reference to each element in the list as it loops through. Using modifiers such as:

```
item[2] = 5
```

will work because you are modifying the reference directly.

However, when you try to set the reference equal to another variable:

`item = some_other_thing`

you are not actually modifying the item, you are modifying the reference to the item, and have therefor never changed the original item, just lost your reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that *assignment never mutates*. It merely creates a new reference, or reassigns a reference (which is what you are doing). You have to use a mutator method, so for example:

```
In [1]: x = [1.2345,0.543895,0.0]
   ...: y = [2,3,4]
   ...: z = [65.34,3.248578493,1.11111]
   ...: for coord in [x,y,z]:
   ...:     coord[:] = [round(item,3) for item in coord]
   ...: print(x,y,z)
   ...:
[1.234, 0.544, 0.0] [2, 3, 4] [65.34, 3.249, 1.111]
```

So, even though `coord[:] = [round(item,r) for item in cord]` **looks** like a regular assignment, it is not. It is syntactic sugar for calling a mutator method, `__setitem__` to be precise:

```
In [2]: coord
Out[2]: [65.34, 3.249, 1.111]

In [3]: coord.__setitem__(slice(None,None), ['foo','bar','baz'])

In [4]: coord
Out[4]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Similarly, `List[0] = 100` is *not assignment*, it is syntactic sugar for:

```
In [6]: List
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3]

In [7]: List[0] = 99

In [8]: List
Out[8]: [99, 2, 3]

In [9]: List.__setitem__(0, 'foo')

In [10]: List
Out[10]: ['foo', 2, 3]
```

You can't modify immutable types because, by definition, *they have no mutator methods*, even though there are operations that *look* like mutator methods:

```
x = 10
x += 10 # looks like a mutator method but actually assigns a new object to x
```

Note, a `str` is similar to a list. You can slice it, but the corresponding mutator method doesn't exist:

```
In [17]: s = 'abcdefg'

In [18]: s[:3]
Out[18]: 'abc'

In [19]: s.__getitem__(slice(0,3))
Out[19]: 'abc'

In [20]: s.__setitem__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-44ee26769121> in <module>()
----> 1 s.__setitem__

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example did not work because `coord` is only a reference to to the lists `x`, `y`, and `z`. When you reassign `coord`, you are overwriting the original reference and setting `coord` to reference a new list object.

In other words `coord` is not a *pointer* to each list. Rather, it is only a reference. And when you reassign `coord`, you lose the original reference.

You can remedy this problem by mutating the list object `coord` is referencing:

```
>>> x = [1.2345, 0.543895, 0.0]
>>> y = [2, 3, 4]
>>> z = [65.34, 3.248578493, 1.11111]
>>> 
>>> for coord in [x, y, z]:
    coord[:] = [round(item,3) for item in coord]


>>> x
[1.234, 0.544, 0.0]
>>> y
[2, 3, 4]
>>> z
[65.34, 3.249, 1.111]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In all your cases, the loop variable is just an alias for each element in the thing being looped over.

The reason `List` in your second example works like you want it to, but `coord` in your third example doesn't, is that in the second example, you're changing an element of the list pointed to by `List`, and therefore actually updating the underlying data.

In the third example, you're trying to directly change `coord`, and thus are just updating the alias to point to a different list, instead of using the alias to access the underlying array and changing it. As a result, `coord` now just points to a different list. Consider this modified version of your second example:

```
for List in [listA,listB]:
    List = [7,8,9]
print(listA) # prints [1,2,3]; underlying data not changed
print(List) # prints [7,8,9]; List now points to the new array
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify elements of the list, you need to provide the index and then modify. In other words, this will not modify anything in the list:

```
arr=[1,2,3]
for x in arr:
     x+=1 #not modifying the values in the list
     print(x) #this will print 2,3,4
print(arr) #prints [1,2,3]
```

So even though you incremented the values but you did not replace the values in the list

What you need to do is, use the index to change the values

```
arr=[1,2,3]
for x in range(len(arr)): #len(arr) evaluates to 3 and range(3) makes an array of numbers from 0 up to but not including 3
   arr[x]=arr[x]+1
print[arr] #Now prints [2,3,4]
```